# Show with resolution proof that expression is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the boolean expression:

$$ ((\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg C))\implies (A\implies \neg C) $$

I have reshaped this so far that no equivalence and no implication is included. 
As far as I know, it is important for the resolution that the Boolean function is in CNF. 
My transformation then flows into this expression:
$$ ((\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg C))\implies (A\implies \neg C) $$
$$ ((\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg C))\implies (\neg A \lor \neg C) $$
$$ \neg((\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg C))\lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) $$
$$ (\neg(\neg A \lor B) \lor \neg(\neg B \lor \neg C))\lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) $$
$$ ((A \land \neg B) \lor (B \land C))\lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) $$
That is not yet CNF form, right?
My question is therefore, can someone go to me the transformation steps? How to get to the CNF form?

If I had the CNF form, I could show a tautology with the resolution. For this I need the clause set from the CNF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get into CNF, distribute any $\lor$'s over $\land$'s. So:

$$ ((A \land \neg B) \lor (B \land C))\lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ (((A \land \neg B) \lor B) \land (A \land \neg B) \lor C))) \lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ ((A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor B) \land (A \lor C) \land (\neg B \lor C)) \lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ ((A \lor B) \land \top \land (A \lor C) \land (\neg B \lor C)) \lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ ((A \lor B) \land (A \lor C) \land (\neg B \lor C)) \lor (\neg A \lor \neg C) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ ((A \lor B)  \lor (\neg A \lor \neg C)) \land ((A \lor C)  \lor (\neg A \lor \neg C)) \land ((\neg B \lor C) \lor (\neg A \lor \neg C)) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ (A \lor B  \lor \neg A \lor \neg C) \land (A \lor C  \lor \neg A \lor \neg C) \land (\neg B \lor C \lor \neg A \lor \neg C) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ \top \land \top \land \top \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\top$$

Hmmm....

OK, so we have taken the statement as is and proven it to be a tautology!

... but not through resolution ...

In fact,  you got the wrong set-up! To prove this statement to be a tautology through resolution, you need to first *negate* the statement, and then put it into CNF, thus into clauses, and then derive the empty clause through resolution:

$$ \neg (((\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg C))\to (A\to \neg C)) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ ((\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg C))\land \neg (A \to \neg C)  \Leftrightarrow$$

$$ (\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg C)\land A \land C$$

This is now in CNF! ... and you will find resolution is now trivial

Comment: Hi and thank you for your good answer!
So if I understand that correctly, I must first negate the first expression and then reshape it into CNF correctly.
So:
$ \ neg (((\ neg A \ lor B) \ land (\ neg B \ lor \ neg C)) \ implies (A \ implies \ neg C)) $

Comment: @JohnSchulz Yes!  Just added that to the answer ... and sorry, I can't bring myself to use $\Rightarrow$ for the conditional; I much prefer to use $\rightarrow$

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I'm just trying to understand your transformation exactly.

Comment: @JohnSchulz Sorry if that went a bit fast ... I used the equivalence $\neg (P \to Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land \neg Q$.  But you can always derive that: $\neg (P \to Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg (\neg P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg P \land \neg Q \Leftrightarrow P \land \neg Q$. ... oh, and I had a negation that shouldn't have been there ... fixed!

Comment: Ah ok, now it's true for me too. I've been thinking all the time about recalculating your solution that I made a mistake. But nice that you have corrected the error yet! Now I understand the solution completely! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnSchulz Great! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Does this results in the clause set 
M = {{\ neg a, b}, {\ neg b, \ neg c}, {a}, {c}}

Comment: @JohnSchulz Yes, correct! So that's easy to resolve ....

Comment: Hey @Bram28,
I saw in your other comments how you continued to work. However, the question arises as to which pattern you have used to do this. Is it about finding all the combinations of clauses, or just trying to somehow reach the empty clause?
If I just do it now, it looks something like this:
$$ 1\quad {\neg A,B} $$
$$ 2\quad {\neg B, \neg C} $$
$$ 3\quad {A} $$
$$ 4\quad {C} $$
$$ 5\quad {B} \quad\text{1 & 3}$$
$$ 6\quad {\neg B} \quad\text{2 & 4} $$
$$ 7\quad {\square} \quad\text{5 & 6} $$
I came on the way through trying out. Do you have to find all combinations?

Comment: @JohnSchulz You just have to get an empty clause; no need to find all possible resolutions. So, what you have there is good!

Comment: Great, that makes me happy, if I have thought so far correctly.
I've seen that often a resolution tree is drawn. I can create this from the transformations that I did before to reach the empty clause, right?

Comment: @JohnSchulz Correct. Start with 1,2,3,4 on top, 5 and 6 on a second 'level', and 7 at the bottom, and draw lines according to the resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $(X\wedge Y)\to Z$ is a tautology, *by resolution*, you seek to prove $(X\wedge Y\wedge\neg Z)$ is a contradiction (ie false).   After all, if the junction of $X$ and $Y$ does imply $Z$ then it shall contradict $\neg Z$.

So, since the negation of $A\to\neg C$ is $A\wedge\neg\neg C$, therefore to prove $((\neg A\vee B)\wedge(\neg B\vee\neg C))\to(A\to\neg C)$, you must simply show that $((\neg A\vee B)\wedge(\neg B\vee\neg C))\wedge(A\wedge\neg\neg C)$ is a contradiction.

That is, that the clausal form $\{(\neg A, B),(\neg B,\neg C),(A),(\neg\neg C)\}$ may be resolved to an empty set.

Comment: Hi, why is your clausal form not: M = {{\ neg a, b}, {\ neg b, \ neg c}, {a}, {c}}?
I have a logic book in which this topic is unfortunately poorly explained. But there is something like this as an example:
a = (p \ lor q \ lor \ neg r) \ land (\ neg p) ...
Which results in the following clause amount:
M = {{p, q, \ negr}, {\ neg p}, ...}

Comment: Because of a typo.

Comment: Ok, that explanins my question. Thank you, too.
Then you can ignore my objection above :)